# Wpf change property action from xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to change state from xaml? For example when first button firing 
assigh "State" some value string or bool. What need to write in   . What should be in target name?

```
    <Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="State"  Value="False"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="94,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication114
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Data();
    }
}
public class Data
{
    private string state;
    public string State 
    {
        get { return this.state; }
        set { this.state = value; }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi If I have not misunderstood your question you can do it like this

TriggerAction class

```
    public class TriggerActionClick : TriggerAction<Button>
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string TargetName { get; set; }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        if (AssociatedObject.DataContext != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TargetName))
        {
            var type=AssociatedObject.DataContext.GetType();
            var prop = type.GetProperty(TargetName);
            if (prop != null)
                prop.SetValue(AssociatedObject.DataContext,Value);
        }

    }
}
```

Here when you click the Button the Value set in xaml will be set to the Property specified in TargetName of the DataContext object.